# Piano Unreachable Notes in Music Sheet

Tags: piano, sheet-music, fingering

Pardon my novelty,
I'm new to reading music sheet, but now after some time I can basically read notes.

This question is for piano.

From this music sheet
https://musescore.com/user/30710562/scores/6138973

I find some combination of multiple notes impossible to reach by my finger, at least one note of them remaining impossible to reach. As the notes in column highlighted below.
[image]
[image]
[image]
My hands above are how I've tried my best to stretch my fingers to reach the notes. Yet the note E6 is still impossible to reach.

Is my fingers position wrong? Or is there any other trick?
Or really it is impossible? If it's impossible, why the music sheet writer put that unreachable note in there?
And what am I supposed to do? Ignore that unreachable note?

Comment: The music is impossible as written because whoever wrote has no idea what they're doing. The impossible chords are only part of the problem. Leave out anything you can't play.

Comment: @PiedPiper - This sheet music is not impossible to anyone whose hands can each span a 10th. Otherwise, we'd be dismissing quite a lot of Tom Brier (ragtime) compositions as "impossible" due to similar issues, this time in the left hand - even though we have direct video evidence of Tom Brier playing those own works of his.

Comment: @Dekkadeci It's not just a 10th, it's a 10th with the hand contorted in order to play the C5-E5. This is not going to be possible unless you can reach a much larger interval. I can easily play a white key 10th, but I cannot play C5-E5-E6 by a long shot. And playing it as written as a 13th in the left hand has similar problems.

Comment: As @PiedPiper, this is a badly written arrangement, which is very typical of MuseScore. See the duplicate question for options on how to play the highlighted chord.

Comment: I think Rachmaninoff could could have done it, but I do agree that this is rather optimistic. Most likely this arrangement was written on notation application only. Also, to be brutally honest, it is not particularly good, a major part of the arrangement consists of two voices, both in octaves.

Comment: @Dekkadeci I can easily span a tenth, but getting my forefinger to play a third away from my thumb is indeed as MattPutnam says very awkward at best.  And anyway, if the arranger did know what they were doing, the top two notes of the chord on the lower staff would be on the upper staff.  PiedPiper's assessment of the arranger's competence is somewhere between right and generous.

Comment: @Dekkadeci I missed the fact that the RH is loco just for that one 'E'. The rest of my comment still applies.

Comment: After listening to the original I must redeem my statement, this arrangement is exactly as good as the original.